Table with nested rows and columns
I am trying to reproduce this table but I am encountering difficulties.

What I tried :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Instant} & \textbf{Avancement} & \textbf{C$_4$H$_8$O$_2$(aq)} & \textbf{Na$^+$(aq)} & \textbf{HO$^-$(aq)} & \textbf{Na$^+$(aq)} & \textbf{CH$_3$CO$_2^-$(aq)} & \textbf{C$_2$H$_5$OH(aq)} \\ 
\hline
0 & 0 & C$_0$.V & C$_0$.V & C$_0$.V & & & \\ 
\hline
$t$ & $X$ & & & & & & \\ 
\hline
$\infty$ & $X_m$ & & & & & & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

The result :


Use \multicolumn

You can use \multicolumn to make a big cell and mhchem to make easily the reaction (but with a smaller font), but this way you cannot align the columns with the reaction. If this is the goal, then is better split the reaction in cells and avoid the the multicolumn cell. On the other hand, I strongly suggest avoid the vertical lines and use the booktabs package:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\noindent\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccccccc@{}}\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Reaction} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\footnotesize \ce{C4H8O2_{(aq)} + Na^+_{(aq)} + HO^-_{(aq)} -> Na+_{(aq)} + CH3CO^-_2_{(aq)} + C2H5OH_{(aq)} }}}\\\cmidrule(r){1-2}
{Instant} & {Avancement} & \makebox[4em]{}  & \makebox[3em]{} & \makebox[2.5em]{}  &  &  & \\\midrule 
0 & 0 & C$_0$.V & C$_0$.V & C$_0$.V & xxxxxx & xxxxxxxx  &  xxxx  \\ 
$t$ & $X$ & & & & & & \\ 
$\infty$ & $X_m$ & & & & & & \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\noindent\centering
\tabcolsep3pt
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{\quad}ccccccccccc@{}}\toprule
 &  &  \multicolumn{11}{c}{Reaction (aq)} \\\cmidrule{3-13} 
Instant & Avancement &  
\ce{C4H8O2}&+&\ce{Na+}&+&\ce{HO-}&\ce{->}&\ce{Na+}&+&\ce{CH3CO^-2}&+&\ce{C2H5OH}\\\midrule
0 & 0 & C$_0$.V & &  C$_0$.V & & C$_0$.V &&  xxx && xxx &&  xxx \\ 
$t$ & $X$ & & & & & & \\ 
$\infty$ & $X_m$ & & & & & & \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

